# Why was my question downvoted without comments? (As in specific case, not in general)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, downvote-reason

I've asked a question about tables and HTML. I did some research before asking, but did not found solutions good enough (eg. nothing about built-in methods, solutions requiring overcomplicated code, etc.), that's why I asked here.

The particular question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513383/add-ability-to-select-rows-in-table
*I'm not linking it for attention/publicity*, but for getting an answer about the downvotes - since (as far as I know) they reduce visiblity and chance for getting an answer; *I just want some answers about what did I do wrong.*

Comment: It was downvoted without comment because the downvoter(s) decided to not comment.

Comment: We can't read the mind of the voter. We don't even know who voted.

Comment: "What would be the best/easiest way" -> opinion based **and** -> too broad.

Comment: Some people did vote to close, that gives a hint as to what people might think is wrong with your question. Whether the set of people who downvoted is a subset of or even intersects with those that voted to close, you can't know, but it's reasonable to assume.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *We can't read the mind of the voter*, I thought this is included in the mod tools, isn't it :)? Or does it still takes 6 to 8 weeks to implement it?

Comment: @DavidPostill So this may be/is the reason. The "put on hold" reason on the question is much more helpful than the downvotes themselves, thanks! Unfortunately in this case I need to look for a single solution, not ask the community to suggest one from the many.

Comment: @Executioner Have you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If users have the feeling you didn't [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-mvc-4%5D++gridview+is%3Aq) and showed why the search results didn't solve your problem make a question receive down votes as well...

Comment: Per the downvote tooltip: *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."* Or maybe [Tim dropped his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/248731).

Comment: "I did some research before asking" amazing how so many people make this claim, yet none of this information ever makes it in their questions.  Asking for help is why SO is here. Asking for us to do your work for you is not.  In fact, many people feel it is rude.  SO should be your last stop, not your first.  And you should include details as to *why* it is your last stop in your question, **otherwise people answering will waste their time (!!!!!) telling you things you've already done.** And how rude is that?

Comment: @Will - ask for a few links from their search history - that usually shuts them up because, or course, they have none.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem with this question is that **it's entirely too broad.**  The fact that no one commented is that simply no one decided to.

For those < 10K, here is the question verbatim.

> What would be the best/easiest way to create a table within HTML with
>   the ability to select rows? Similar to dataGridView in DotNet-Win32.
>
> Would be used with ASP.NET-MVC4 (Razor engine).

The biggest red flag here is "best", since there's no one best way to do anything.  Without much more to go off of, it sounds like you're asking us to do this for you.

If it were a slightly better question, it'd have a little more detail to it, including but not limited to:

- Describing **what work you had done** to motivate this goal
- Clarifying what you mean about the ability to select rows
- What the `dataGridView` piece means to you and why you want it to be similar to what you're working with

Normally I comment on questions that I think could be redeemed, but personally I'd downvote and close this one.  It's too broad for the site.